# Flutter Demo page is showing instead of my code on web

Tags: flutter, nginx, flutter-web

I tried possible every solution, I also compiled repos with Flutter Web (Flutter gallery and others) and no matter what the default demo home page is showing. I was thinking it may something to do with nginx config however I unsure what it might be.

I am copying `build/web` to the server.

Here is my Flutter code:

```
void main() {
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
      title: 'TEST DEX',
    );
  }

  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const IndexPage();
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IndexPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const IndexPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color:Colors.red);
  }
}
```

And here is my nginx config:

```
# ssl
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/nginx-certificate.crt; ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/nginx.key;
# api backend
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name testpage.net;
  location /api {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers
'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffers 32 4k;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6969/;
  }
location / {
# based on internet this should be no cache options
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
        root /home/testpage/www/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
}
```

It seems like weird behavior, if I substitute index.html with anything it works just fine. It also works normally I debug it locally and no residual files are left, with each update I am cleaning it. But no matter what I do I still see this:

[image: Flutter Demo Home Page]

Comment: You need to clear the browser cache. Press ctrl+F5 while opening the page

Comment: @Schaban issue lied in different part, basically what works is to go to page.com and what does not work is page.com/ 

I would really appreciate different sort of error, then just displaying the demo page. Given the error might come from nginx or Flutter itself. Seems like a really stupid mistake to make, I discovered just a minute ago, I was in process of writing answer here.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was quite simple, I was accessing the webpage by typing `page.com/` and not just `page.com`

Thus the issue was writing extra `/`. It was really confusing situation with simple solution.

Not sure where the error came from if it was nginx sending me some cached website or Flutter itself, but I would appreciate better explained error. There was nothing in the browser console, which would suggest this grave issue.